# Intuitive idea for Dini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can someone come up with an intuition for why Dini's theorem (A monotone sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a continuous function on a compact set converges uniformly) has to be true? I feel like forcing the convergence to not be uniform would break the continuity of the limit function somehow but don't see what role the monotonicity would play in this. I've seen several proofs for this but still miss the idea for why the theorem should hold.

Comment: If $\phi_n\nearrow\phi$, then The sets $U_n=\{\phi-\phi_n<\varepsilon\}$ are open, cover the whole space and $U_n\subset U_{n+1}$, Th rest is compactness of the space.

Comment: It's always instructive to find for oneself a counterexample when the necessary hypothesis (in this case, monotonicity) is removed. This is an important step in learning mathematics. In this case, there are abundant counterexamples.